# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 Unsupported Media Type[EDITED]

Tags: android, spring, post, resttemplate

In Android web service using POST method of REST TEMPLATE, I am trying to send an object to server which contains few parameters and and 2 Objects. Those 2 Objects contains few parameters and 3 Lists of different Objects and each of those 3 Lists of Objects contains few parameters inside them and 1 List of Object that contains a byte array alone. Like in the below pics:

Pic 1[Main Object(The one I am trying to send)]:

[image: Main Object(The one I am trying to send)]

Pic 2[Object inside the Main Object comprising 3 Lists of Objects]:

[image: Object inside the Main Object comprising 3 Lists of Objects]

Pic 3[An Object as List comprising 1 List of Another Object inside it, likewise for the other 2(Accommodation & Others)]:

[image: An Object as List comprising 1 List of Another Object inside it, likewise for the other 2(Accommodation & Others)]

Pic 4[List of Object inside the sub-Object containing a byre array parameter alone]:

[image: List of Object inside the sub-Object containing a byre array parameter alone]

And my code for webservice POST method:

```
public static final String capUrl = "http://192.168.1.7:8084/CAPWS";

public Expenses setExpensesByBatch(Expenses expenses) {

    try {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());

        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> list = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        list.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(list);


        String b = restTemplate.postForObject(capUrl + "/UX/", expenses, String.class);

        Log.e("String ===============b", b + "     ++++");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("expObjPost_WsCli_EX", e.toString());
    }
    return expenses;
}
```

Whatever I do it returns `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 Unsupported Media Type`

My `LOGCAT` below:

[image: LOGCAT]

My server side code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = CapRestURIConstants.UPDATEEXPENSES, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody
String updateExpenses(@RequestBody Expenses expenses) {
    String response = "true";

    System.out.println("incoming--------" + "UPDATEEXPENSES");
    try {
        if (expenses != null) {
            //System.out.println("expenses--------" + expenses);

            int catType = expenses.getCategoryType();
            String categoryType = String.valueOf(catType);

            String categoryId = expenses.getCategoryId();
            String batchId = expenses.getBatchId();

            System.out.println("categoryType--------" + categoryType);
            System.out.println("categoryId--------" + categoryId);
            System.out.println("batchId--------" + batchId);

            Batch batch = getBatchById(batchId);
            if (batch != null) {

                expenseDataNew(batch, expenses);
                expenseImagesNew(batch, expenses);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "faslse";
    }
    return response;
}

public void expenseDataNew(Batch batch, Expenses expenses) {

    Session session = null;
    Transaction transaction = null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try {

        LinkedTreeMap masterMap = (LinkedTreeMap) gson.fromJson(batch.getMasterJson(), Object.class);
        LinkedTreeMap expenseObject = (LinkedTreeMap) masterMap.get("2007");

        masterMap.replace(expenseObject, expenses);
        String masterJson = gson.toJson(masterMap);
        batch.setMasterJson(masterJson);

        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(batch);

        transaction.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}

public void expenseImagesNew(Batch batch, Expenses expenses) {

    Session session = null;
    Transaction transaction = null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try {

        // DIVERTING TO IMAGE DB
        session = ImageHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        if (expenses != null) {


            int catType = expenses.getCategoryType();
            String categoryType = String.valueOf(catType);
            System.out.println("categoryType--------" + categoryType);

            String categoryId = expenses.getCategoryId();
            System.out.println("categoryId--------" + categoryId);

            String travelExpenseImgId = "f257f225-41da-11e7-be05-001d92ba9634";
            String accommodationExpenseImgId = "204b4baf-41db-11e7-be05-001d92ba9634";
            String otherExpenseImgId = "45d31872-41db-11e7-be05-001d92ba9634";

            AssessorExpense assessorExpense = expenses.getAssessorExpense();
            TCExpense tCExpense = expenses.getTcExpense();

            Boolean isTravel, isAccomadation, isOthers;

            List<Travel> travelList;
            List<Accomadation> accommodationList;
            List<Others> othersList;

            ArrayList proof;
            Expense expense;
            ExpenseImage expenseImage;

            // categoryType: 1 = Assessor
            // categoryType: 4 = TC
            if (categoryType.equals("1")) {

                if (assessorExpense != null) {

                    isTravel = assessorExpense.isTravel();
                    if (isTravel) {

                        travelList = (ArrayList) assessorExpense.getTravel();
                        System.out.println("travelList.size()==" + travelList.size());

                        expense = getExpense(travelExpenseImgId);
                        System.out.println("expense==travel==1==:" + expense);
                        String expenseStr = String.valueOf(expense);
                        System.out.println("expenseStr==travel==1==:" + expenseStr);


                        for (Travel travel : travelList) {

                            List<ExpenseImageObject> expenseImageObjects = (ArrayList) travel.getExpenseImageObjects();
                            System.out.println("travel==expenseImageObjects.size()== :" + expenseImageObjects.size());

                            for (ExpenseImageObject image : expenseImageObjects) {

                                System.out.println("expense===travel==for==:" + expense);

                                expenseImage = new ExpenseImage();

                                expenseImage.setBatchId(batch.getBatchId());
                                expenseImage.setCategoryId(expenses.getCategoryId());
                                expenseImage.setExpimgId(expenseStr);
                                expenseImage.setImage(image.getImage());
                                expenseImage.setStatus(1);   // dummy status 1 - Travel, 2 - Accommodation, 3 - Other

                                session.saveOrUpdate(expenseImage);                                    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        transaction.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am actually trying to send an object with lists of data as well list of photos in each list to the server.
Browsed through several websites and almost all topics related to the error on `Stack Overflow`, Been sitting on this issue for more than a week. Hope I would find some help.

Comment: We must see what is expected by your endpoint.

Comment: I get an error stating `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 Unsupported Media Type`. I doesn't even get any log on server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a hell lot of research and experts suggestions, I finally managed to find the solution to my problem. The problem is not with the code. Its actually perfect. The problem is with the Objects I use to get & set. I am using *NetBeans* for server side coding. What I did was, I created my necessary Objects in *Android studio*, copied the *parameters*, *getters & setters* and pasted them on *NetBeans*, Object class. The problem was with the booleans I've been using. The *booleans* that are created on *Android Studio* didn't support on *NetBeans* in some cases, that prevented hitting the server. And after getting expert advice, I did the Object creation on *NetBeans* copied the *parameters*, *getters & setters* and pasted them on *Android Studio* Object class. And then it worked well. Took me more than 2 weeks to solve this issue. Hope this would be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the call to something like this

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.add("Accept","application/json;charset=utf-8");

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
...
HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(req, headers);
responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request,
    String.class);
```

to specify content type

UPDATE

`req` is in fact body you send to the server.  It could be e.g.

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> req ...
```

There you in fact send request body and headers.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the last 2 lines  `HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(req, headers);
responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request,
    String.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using "HttpHeaders" to set the content-type header explicitly to what is expected by the endpoint.
Then you use the "HttpEntity" with both your header and your body classes.
Example :

```
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>("my body", requestHeaders);

    byte[] response = restTemplate.postForObject(
            "URL", httpEntity, byte[].class);
```