# Create a Validation that will take jsonPath and type, Check whether the data type is same for the jsonpath and the type

Tags: java, json

I am reading one file, IN that Json data is available.
I need to create a method, Which takes jsonobject, jsonpath,type
I need to check the datatype of jsonpath, type...If the datatype is same it should return true else false...

Example : store.book[0].title.... this is the jsonpath and it will return title value as a string
so if the type which we given as a string ...it should return true..

```
Json Data : 
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },

    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

This the java Code for reading the Json file and getting the output..
Example : store.book[0].title.... this is the jsonpath and it will return title value as a string,
so if the type which we given as a string ...it should return true..

```
public class Validation {

    public void readJSON() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("myJSONFile.txt");
        String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "utf-8");

        // Convert JSON string to JSONObject
        JSONObject tomJsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
        System.out.println(tomJsonObject);
        System.out.println(tomJsonObject.getString("age"));
        //validateByType(tomJsonObject, "age", null);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Test");
        Validation v = new Validation();
        try {
            v.readJSON();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not create objects wrt the JSON? So that you can check for null!

Comment: Ya sure... Can you help in that ... Thanks

Comment: You can do it by creating Object classes with reference to the fields available in the JSON, and generate getters and setters ii the object classes. So, that you may use the objects globally.

Comment: Can you give me a code example of it?? I am perrty new to this coding..

Answer (score 0):

Why not create objects wrt the JSON? So that you can check for null! You can do it by creating Object classes with reference to the fields available in the JSON, and generate getters and setters for the fields in the object classes. So, that you may use the objects globally. Object creation sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56404751/4116560) and also in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44277442/4116560) question.